# Load balance by header prefix

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I need to balance an OAuth application. By using the `Authorization` header, I can redirect the same client to the same machine - however - I want to redirect each user to the same machine, regardless of their IP or authorization token.

Therefore I prepend the user-id to the auth token.

Is it possible with HAproxy/nginx etc. to **balance by header prefix** (or a header sub-range)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with generic-nginx i think this isnt possible; but you could use the [lua-module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_headers) to filter for headers and then `do_stuff` like setting variables or creating sub_requests etc.

lua is quite helpful for such nasty hacks, but you probably have to cmpile nginx to fit your needs. but then you can have lua + memcache, and its fast as hell.

Comment: Already wrote my own LB in golang. Was the best fit since I also need to handle Websocket connections besides HTTP/S and TCP.